# Excel VBA: Userform code replaces row content instead of adding a new one

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm a beginner, learning to code in VBA and this is my first post. I've been struggling lately on how to get my UserForm to work.

This is the code for the "Add" button in my UserForm, when ever I would run that macro (by pressing the add button) it would take the top row of my sheet and replace the content of the cells.

What I'm trying to achieve is actually adding a new row to the sheet with all the info I inputted. It's been a few days that I'm struggling so that's why (after intensive google searches) I finally decide to ask you guys for some help :) Hope I was clear enough.

Have a nice day,

`Dim L As Integer`

`If MsgBox("Are you sure to create a new row with those information ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
     L = Sheets("BDD").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Adding the new line to the sheet`

```
 Range("B" & L).Value = CboResp.Text
 Range("C" & L).Value = CboStat.Text
 Range("D" & L).Value = CboNat.Text
 Range("E" & L).Value = CboPrio.Text
 Range("F" & L).Value = CboAff.Text
 Range("G" & L).Value = CboLea.Text
 Range("H" & L).Value = txtDateRD.Text
 Range("I" & L).Value = txtDateEnv.Text
 Range("J" & L).Value = CboIni.Text
 Range("K" & L).Value = CboISAV.Text
 Range("L" & L).Value = txtVin.Text
 Range("M" & L).Value = txtContrat.Text
 Range("N" & L).Value = txtClientFinal.Text
 Range("O" & L).Value = txtImmat.Text
 Range("P" & L).Value = txtNomCon.Text
 Range("Q" & L).Value = txtPrenomCon.Text
 Range("R" & L).Value = txtTelCon.Text
 Range("S" & L).Value = txtMotif.Text
 Range("T" & L).Value = txtDateRDV.Text
 Range("U" & L).Value = txtDateInter.Text
 Range("V" & L).Value = CboVH.Text
 Range("W" & L).Value = txtComment.Text
 Range("X" & L).Value = CboCon.Text
```

`End If`

Comment: That will happen if there's no value in Col A in your last row of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more robust:

```
Dim L As Long

If MsgBox("Are you sure to create a new row with those information ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then

    With Sheets("BDD")
         L = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Adding the new line to the sheet

         .Range("B" & L).Value = CboResp.Text
         .Range("C" & L).Value = CboStat.Text
         .Range("D" & L).Value = CboNat.Text
         .Range("E" & L).Value = CboPrio.Text
         .Range("F" & L).Value = CboAff.Text
         .Range("G" & L).Value = CboLea.Text
          'etc etc
     End with
End If
```

Assuming there is always a value in ColA for each row of added data.

Comment: You are correct about the range. Since the Column A was blank the code would not work. Followed your recommendation and changed the range to B and everything is working now! Many thanks!